# Passing a list of one function to another, across different directories

Tags: r, directory, apply

I am trying to assign random numbers to a copy of a file in various directories (tricky to replicate). The directory structure is as follows:

```
1100    
1100/Images
```

I first create the new directories and copy the images across. For this I have the following working

```
NewImageGen <- function(singledir){
  #
  Directoryforrandoms <- "RandomNumAsignment"
  Directoryforrandoms <- paste(singledir, "/", Directoryforrandoms, sep = "")
  dir.create(Directoryforrandoms,
             showWarnings = F)
  #
  Imagedir <- paste(singledir, '/Images', sep = '')
  filestocopy <- list.files(Imagedir,
                            recursive = F,
                            full.names = T)
  file.copy(from = filestocopy,
            to = Directoryforrandoms,
            overwrite = F)
  #
  newfiles <- list.files(path = Directoryforrandoms,
                         pattern = ".tif", # they are all tiff files
                         full.names = T)
  #
  return(newfiles)
}
NewImages <- pblapply(alldirs, FUN = NewImageGen)
```

This gives me a large list, which is divided into four (due to there being four directories in this instance). I want to pass the `newfiles` to another function which generates a random number prefix and sticks it on the front. I can do this on a regular list of files using:

```
RandomNumGen <- function(singleimg){
  randomnumber <- as.character(sample(100000:999999, 1, replace=F))
  singlerename <- sub('^', randomnumber, singleimg)
  file.rename(from = singleimg,
              to = singlerename)
}
```

It runs through all elements of the list but returns a frustrating `false`.

Any help would be top notch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pblapply()` returns a `list` while `list.files()` returns a character vector.
So if your function works with the return value of `list.files()` try changing your call from `pblapply()` to `pbsapply()`.

**Edit:**

`newfiles`, i.e. the return value of the `NewImageGen()` function, contains full paths (as you set `full.names = T` in the last `list.files()` call).

`sub('^', randomnumber, singleimg)` will add the random number before the first part of the path like `677570/home/Jim/1100/Images/RandomNumAsignment/original_image_name.tif`.

Instead you want to do

```
file.path(dirname(singleimg), sub('^', randomnumber, basename(singleimg))
```

Comment: thanks for your response, unfortunately it also returns all values as false. This makes me wonder if there is something wrong in the function

Comment: `newfiles`, i.e. the return value of the `NewImageGen()` function, contains full paths (as you set `full.names = T` in the last `list.files()` call). `sub('^', randomnumber, singleimg)` will add the random number before the first part of the path like `677570/home/Jim/1100/Images/RandomNumAsignment/original_image_name.tif`. Instead you want to do `file.path(dirname(singleimg), sub('^', randomnumber, basename(singleimg))`. Does this help?

Comment: It seems so obvious now! Thank you, it works a treat. Post it as an answer! thanks so much. Now I just need to wait an hour for it to run...